# Pull regex match without its environment

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to match in Python any occurences of something between given expression. For example:

```
dogdogacowadogdog  <-- search a word between 'a' characters
<span>tiger<a>      <-- search for sth between <span> and <a>
```

I'd like to match only this *something* between, so it would `cow` and `tiger` respectively. However, when using rexexes:

```
r'a(.*)a'
r'<span>(.*)<a>'
```

It prints me the whole line and not only this what I am looking for (what is matched by `(.*)`). How can I pull this information?

Comment: It sounds like you want `(.*?)` (lazy matching). Also I hope you're not parsing HTML with regex...

Comment: Which `re` function are you using?

Comment: you have to use the capturing group.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81: match = re.search(regex, text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is [non-greedy](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) matching.

**What is *non-greedy* matching?**

`.*`, `.+` and `.?` attempt to match as many characters as possible. Adding a question mark (`?`) after these characters attempts to match the least characters possible. `.*?` will match 0 chars if it can and `.+?` will match 1.

Back to your question, you should use this as your regex query:

```
r'a(.*?)a'
r'<span>(.*?)<a>'
```

**Next up is the matching itself**:

If you use `match =`[`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.search) you need to get [`match.group(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.match.group) and not `match.group(0)` in order to receive the group itself.

`match.group(0)` gives out the entire match (including the part before and after the group).

`match.group(1)` gives out only the first group.

[`match.groups()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.match.groups) however takes out only the groups (not the entire match), so `match.groups()[0]` will be the first group.

Comment: Could you explain in short why should .group(1) and not .group(0) be used?

Comment: group(0) is the whole match ie the first capturing group

Comment: @BartłomiejSzałach Further explained in the answer. The links reference to the correct parts in the `re` documentation for further explanation of that behavior.